# После импорта модуля с черепашкой, print выводится два раза. А почему?

Tags: python

После импорта модуля с черепашкой, `print` выводится два раза. А почему? Как это исправить?

```
import turtle

s = 'рандомная строка'
print(s)
```

вывод:

```
рандомная строка
рандомная строка
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никогда не называйте свою программу на Питоне так же, как называется библиотечный модуль, который вы пытаетесь импортировать.

Фактически, вы импортируете свою собственную программу. Хорошо, что строка печатается всего два раза и программа не входит в бесконечный цикл импорта.

Comment: Я тупой, спасибо.

Comment: @ДмитрийГалкин Это в общем-то один из самых частых вопросов на SO, многие на эти грабли попадаются.

Comment: @Дмитрий Галкин если ответ вам помог то примите его